Is there any selective membrane for separation of NaCl (200ppm) from a NaOH 50% solution?
I am looking for a selective membrane (if possible) for separation of NaCl (200ppm) from a NaOH 50% solution. Is PVDF membrane appropriate for this issue?

If you checked PVDF Wikipedia page you would realize it is not compatible with strong bases.

What is it with some removing of ppm - it's at least 3rd such question in recent memory?

These aren't even as much chemistry as where to get better equipment to shed a few more ppm, for whatever reason...

dear @Mithoron, unfortunately I did not get your point, can you provide further details on this topic? I am not so chemist as you are. thanks.
